# Функция рандом JS

Tags: javascript, массивы

Cоздать функцию, которая заполняет массив рандомными числами и выводит его. Для вывода использовать предыдущуя функцию.

```
function randomArray(randomArray) {

   
let random = [];
    for ( let i = 0; i < 20; i++ ) {
        (Math.round(Math.random(r) * 100));
    } randomArray()
```

что не так?

Answer (score 1):

Что-то такое хотели?

```js
function randomArray() {
  let random = [];
  for ( let i = 0; i < 20; i++ ) {
        random.push(Math.round(Math.random() * 100));
  } 
  return random; 
 }
 
 console.log(randomArray())
```

Comment: что я не так сделал ?

Comment: да так как раз учу функции вот и незнаю как сделать что бы так было

Comment: не добавили random.push

Comment: и не закрылм блок

Comment: какой сайт лучший для изучение js

Comment: Меогу порекомендовать https://learn.javascript.ru/. "Лучший" это плохой критерий в программировании